# comparar dos fechas en java

Tags: java, xhtml

buenas necesito ayuda tengo este codigo en xhtml y en java el campo me trae la fecha actual y valida hasta ahi todo bien pero que pasa si yo selecciono otra fecha no me la toma y necesito hacer la validacion sobre otra fecha que yo seleccione no solo la actual me pueden ayudar por favor

```js
fechaEmision = new Date();

if (this.facturaReferencia.getFechaEmision() != null) {


  if (this.fechaEmision.compareTo(this.facturaReferencia.getFechaEmision()) > 0) {
    this.addSingleMessageTo(component + "id_fechaEmisionFacturaReferencia", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
      "La fecha del documento soporte debe ser menor a la de la nota.");
    msgs++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-3 ui-md-2">
  <h:outputLabel for="id_fechaHoraEmision" value="Fecha de generación*" />
  <p:calendar id="id_fechaHoraEmision" value="#{crearNotaAjusteView.fechaEmision}" required="false" requiredMessage="Seleccione la Fecha y Hora de Emisión" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" navigator="true" locale="es" readonlyInput="true">
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
  </p:calendar>
  <p:message for="id_fechaHoraEmision">
    <p:autoUpdate></p:autoUpdate>
  </p:message>
</div>
```

Comment: agrega un ejemplo de fechaEmision y de facturaReferencia.getFechaEmision() que estes usando.

Comment: La solución (si he entendido bien el problema), es crear un método que reciba dos fechas y un texto, devuelve un booleano y si es necesario, muestra el texto, esto hace el código más reutilizable, solo tienes que llamar al método con los datos que quieres evaluar, por ejemplo: **if( validaFecha( fechaA, fechaB, mensaje ) ) { hagoAlgo(); }**, espero haber sido claro.